# What's the difference between lower case and upper case "view" in android xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

Recently I've spent over an hour figuring out what was wrong in my xml... until I realised that there are 2 different widgets in android xml: "view" and "View". Both are correct and are not the same since upper case View was giving me errors about classcastexception until I changed it to lower case... When do we use each of these?

Edit:
So in order to create a modified version of existing widget in android XML I had to use lower case "view":

```
<view
    android:id="@+id/mybutton1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="75"
    class="com.example.customui2.MainActivity$ArticleFragment$MyButton"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_button" />
```

the attached to widget class:

```
public static class MyButton extends ImageView
        {

            public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);

            }

        };
```

When used upper case View I was having exception in such a line:

```
MyButton button1 = (MyButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mybutton1);
```

But I also found examples when upper case View was used like in "spacer widget":

```
<View
   android:layout_weight="20" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Hard to answer if you don't post your xml

Comment: You had a `ClassCastException` when using `<View />`? That's kinda weird, you are supposed to use the uppercase one.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code at first. I thought this was rather obvious issue and not worth of posting code but now it's there!

Answer (score 3):

`View` refers to [`android.view.View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and it's the superclass for all views. By itself it doesn't draw anything but is often used as a spacer.

`view` refers to any `View` and the specific class is given in the `class` attribute, `class="com.example.customui2.MainActivity$ArticleFragment$MyButton"` in your case. You could also have written it as

```
<com.example.customui2.MainActivity.ArticleFragment.MyButton ...
```

(though with the link Mike M. posted in the comments I'm not 100% certain it really works with inner classes like this and I don't have a development environment right here to try it out)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you ever seen `<view>` used? This is the first I've heard of it (or it was so long ago, I have forgotten about it). In retrospect, I'm not surprised that it exists, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's rare but I remember seeing the `<view class="..."` construct in an actual codebase while doing consulting for a customer. I don't remember there was a particular reason for it, other that a few years of development legacy and a number of inexperienced developers.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's shown in the Custom Components example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying

Comment: @MikeM.: Ah, interesting -- it's for static inner classes. `$` probably isn't a valid character in XML element names. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`View` likely refers to a class, whereas `view` is a name that you chosen for an instance of an object of that class.

Comment: sorry but I still dont understand why it would throw me a classcastexception if I use upper case in my example instead of lower case